# PROC SQL Incorrectly Eliminating Missing Values in pull from Oracle data base

Tags: sas, missing-data, proc-sql

All my missing values are being deleted when I do not wish them to be.  I am assuming SAS and Oracle are not playing nice - but I do not know the solution.  Thank-you if you can offer any ideas about this error.

Observe the character field SEX has missing values:

```
data test ;
  input name $ sex $ age city $;
  if sex = "NA" then sex=' ';
  if city = "Unk" then city = ' ';
  cards;
Gene  M  62 Saginaw
Cyndi F    45 Unk 
Alice  NA  51 Bay City       
Bob   M   55 Unk
;
proc print data=test; run;
```

[image]

Observe that I can filter on SEX and still have the missing value:

```
proc sql; 
create table que1 as 
select * from test where sex 
not in ('F','M'); 
quit;
proc sql; select * from que1; quit;
```

[image]

Observe a vanilla data pull from an Oracle table via a libname connection:

```
proc sql; 
create table test as 
select * from dss.student_registrations
where term_code gt '201500'
  and row_type = 'E'
/*  and final_grade not in ('AU','WU') */
;quit;
proc freq data=test; tables final_grade / missing; run;
```

[image]

Now I place the limit on final_grade and all the missing values disappear:

```
proc sql; 
create table test as 
select * from dss.student_registrations
where term_code gt '201500'
  and row_type = 'E'
  and final_grade not in ('AU','WU')
;quit;
proc freq data=test; tables final_grade / missing; run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS has binary logic (true/false).  If Final_Grade is null in SAS, `Final_Grade NOT IN ('AU','WU')` will be true.  Oracle has trinary logic (true/false/unknown).  If Final_Grade is null in Oracle, `Final_Grade NOT IN ('AU','WU')` will be unknown.

Although you are writing SAS code, it's passing the code through to Oracle to process.  Suggest you try:

```
where term_code gt '201500'
and row_type = 'E'
and (final_grade not in ('AU','WU') or final_grade is Null)
```

This and many other gotchas for SAS programmers reading from RDBMS are addressed in a nice paper by Mike Rhoads, http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/141-2009.pdf.

Comment: Well, that's interesting.  From what I've read, sometimes SAS processes / sometimes Oracle processes depending on whether or not you write an Oracle compatible query (no SAS specific language).  If I used a SAS specific function, I suppose it would return the expected result.  I'll have to play around with it a little.  Thank-you.

Comment: This is true. I usually avoid implicit pass through for that reason. I like to control whether SAS is doing the processing or the remote database.

Comment: To force SAS to do all processing, use option in libname statement: direct_sql = none ... per http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/68028/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1hrfk5zjg3mi2n16xnrbmf38m2f.htm